# Level and progress bar system

Tags: php

I have a level system already created but I am now working on a progress bar to go with it. The level system checks the database for your exp and has a variation of numbers where it takes `$count >= 100` in this case `100 = level 3` and it will then update the database and set `level` to `3`

One problem, i cant call for the exp amount needed (100) so for the progress bar i cant make it move, and without a max amount all i can do is `$exp / 0`

What is the best way to store each exp amount into a variable? (**without** chaning the system to make it 100exp needed and then adding precentage each level)

level system w/ progress bar:

```
<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){

}else{

// Connect to your database like you normally do, then get any value into the $count variable
$uid = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $datab = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database") or die ("Could not connect to database");
    $userquery = mysqli_query ($datab, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$uid'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      include"user_array.php";
    }

$count = $exp;

if($level == 0){
  $lvl = 1;
}else{
  $lvl = $level;
}
if ($count >= 25000) { $lvl = 50;
  $level_set = "UPDATE users SET level = '50' WHERE id = '$uid'";
  $db->query($level_set);
}

//to save space i have removed everything from level 3 - 50!



else if ($count >= 100) { $lvl = 3;
  $level_set = "UPDATE users SET level = '3' WHERE id = '$uid'";
  $db->query($level_set);
}


else if ($count >= 50) { $lvl = 2;
  $level_set = "UPDATE users SET level = '2' WHERE id = '$uid'";
  $db->query($level_set);
}

}


// ///Progress bar/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ///Calculate precentage $current (current exp count), $total (max)
// ///This will change the width of of the .inner div wich display the progress bar
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$total = $count; //max count for current level
$current = $exp; //current $exp from database
$percent = round(($current/$total) * 100, 1);

?>
```

all i do at the end is make 2 divs and give each some css and color and making the inner div have `width:<?php echo $percent; ?>%;`

Comment: You have all those ifs, you can easily set the value for next level and get the percentage. Though I'd rather just use an array to store the values and do everything in one loop. Also note that you're calling update every time, even if the level is the same that the user already has...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i agree that it isnt the best level system, but its the best i could find that allows me to set exact exp count i want for each level.

if you give it a search on google, most level systems will set a count and then add x% each level. Its easier to give exp a variable then but when i first found the system it was exactly what i was looking for. I whould love to make it more efficient, but my php knowledge dont go too far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have XP points. Then you need:

- Identify which level matches XP (we will call it L)
- Let XPmin the points matching L and XPmax matching L+1

Then the percentage is given by:

`Progress = 100 * (XP - XPmin) / (XPmax - XPmin)`

Bonus:

You should store an array somewhere as a configuration variable which represents your levels:

```
$levels = [ 
  1 => 0,
  2 => 50,
  3 => 100,
  // ... 
]
```

Then a simple loop will find the level for you instead of a giant switch:

```
$actual_level = null;
foreach ($levels as $l => $xp_min) {
  if ($current_xp>$xp_min) break;

  $actual_level = $l;
}
// ERROR, level not found 
if (is_null($actual_level)) die();

// Else $actual_xp is your real level matching $current_xp points
// Do not forget to escape that SQL or use prepared statements!!
$level_set = "UPDATE users SET level = '" . $actual_level ."' WHERE id = '$uid'";
$db->query($level_set);
```

Comment: looks easy enough for me to handle but i get an error with `$actual_level = null;` sais unidentified variable

Answer (score 1):

Much better system than using a huge amount of ifs would be to have the limits in an array

```
$levellimits = [25000, ..., 100, 50];
```

Then you can just loop through it, find the first that is lower than current level and use `$level = 50 - $i`. You can also get the progress to the next level from the array, you just take the value from `$i - 1` (unless $i is zero meaning max level) and use that as maximum.

```
$nextlevel = $levellimits[$i - 1];
$percent = round($current / $nextlevel * 100, 1);
```

Also if you want the progress bar to be inside the level, as is the usual case, use a minimum of current value so the percentage will go from 0 to 100 within the level.

```
$curlevel = $levellimits[$i];
$nextlevel = $levellimits[$i - 1] - $curlevel;
$percent = round(($current - $curlevel) / $nextlevel * 100, 1);
```

For updating the database do use a condition that doesn't update unless the level actually changed. You can do it easily in your code by checking the level in DB against your new level.

Also don't use string literals ('2') for updating an integer and use parameters rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: not sure if i understood it correctly but i wasnt able to get it to work. no error, but it's not able to find my level nor exp so the progress bar shows empty every time